# SSRS Textbox expression modifying

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

i designed a tablix report, i have a text box called Student-Attendance which dispaly the information below.

```
 Student_Attendance

   Sick 
  Absence
  Present
```

I have tried to use IIF statement in order to show it as S,A,P. Other than "IIF" is there anything i could use in order to get my result.

> IIF (Fields!Student_Attendance.value = "Sick", "S" ) and
> IIF(Fields!Student_Attendance.value  = "Absence" , "A")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IIF` Takes 3 arguments

1. The condition (if field = value)
2. What to return if true (e.g. "S")
3. What to return if false - you are missing this

If you want to use IIF then you have to nest the IIFs

```
=IIF(Fields!Student_Attendance.value = "Sick", "S", IIF(Fields!Student_Attendance.value = "Absence" , "A") )
```

What might be simpler is `SWITCH` especially if you have more than a few options, something like this

```
=SWITCH (
Fields!Student_Attendance.value = "Sick", "S",
Fields!Student_Attendance.value = "Absence", "A",
Fields!Student_Attendance.value = "Present", "P"
)
```